# Dollhouse naming conventions

Tags: dollhouse

As far as I can remember in the show we only see the operation of the LA and Washington Dollhouses. LA uses the Nato alphabet to name its dolls, while Washington uses Greek Gods.

In the second season we're told about the opening of the Dubai Dollhouse, which would be the 23rd dollhouse. Is there any information on how the other 20 or so houses name their Actives?